# Dividing points into subregions using hashmaps

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, hash

I have a 2D raster of say 200pixels x 200pixels I want to subdivide this into 400 "buckets" of each 10x10 pixels.

Then I have a list of points ( about 200k ) that I want to map in the aforementioned structure. So if the point falls into the 10x10 area, add it to the bucket.

Now this seems to me something a hashtable could do nicely. I was wondering if this was possible using the STL?

I tried using stl::unordered_map and specifying the amount of buckets but that's not working, it 'ignores' that request. (Because of too many items that are mapped to the same area I presume, but in my case that's not a problem, on the contrary, that's the entire point).

Is there any way of doing this with the STL?

Comment: So you want to divide the canvas into 400 pieces, and want to keep track of them individually.
Each block can contain point within that blocks range.
Right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you're confusing two pieces of terminology.  There are "buckets" in the hash table sense, which are some internal implementation detail used to distribute elements evenly so that lookups tend not to scan over too many useless elements.  There are also "buckets" in the spatial sense, which are partitions of space into regions so that elements belong to exactly one bucket.  Typically, you will have control over the spatial bucketing system yourself (you get to pick where everything is split), but a hash table will not let you control the buckets very precisely.  You may get to pick an initial size, but if the hash table thinks it's a good idea to increase that size in order to improve performance, it almost certainly will do so.  If it didn't, lookup times would be substantially worse.

If you want to split space up into a grid and then distribute points into that grid, the best way to do this would be to create a 2D array (either with raw arrays or using some grid linearization) of `std::unordered_map`s, each of which just holds points in one particular region of space.  That way, if you want to look up an element, you go to the map holding points just for that bucket, then ask the map to look up the value, at which point it consults its own internal bucketing system to find the point that you want.  This means that if you want to split up the points so that you can do interesting queries on the regions of space, the points are stored in buckets specifically dedicated to those regions, but within those buckets they're stored in a hash table to make looking up those points take less time.

Alternatively, you might want to consider using a spatial data structure like a quadtree or kd-tree, which store the elements efficiently and let you query every point in a spatial bucket efficiently.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sometimes, the biggest challange is understanding what they "need" and not to get confused with what they "want". Nice job at understanding with little hints. :)

Comment: As with all spatial data structures, the real question about the correct structure to use boils down to intended usage for the structure. kd-tree's are amazing at adaptive storage for log(n) point searching or nearest neighbor. In the rendering arena, they are popular with RayTracers. In the physics arena they are sometimes used for pruning primitives for collision detection. As I answered below, for integer based points, you can create a hashing scheme for points and use the hash table for storage, but as mentioned in this answer, may not be the best method.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I typed this out a bit too tired and a bit too late. When I was thinking about it this morning I realised my mistake :).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hash code for the buckets like:

[top 4 bytes are x][lower 4 bytes are y]

```
size_t hash = (p.X / 10) << 16 | (p.Y / 10);

map[hash].push_back(hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is not 'bucket' but maps.
You want something like  maps of maps

```
typedef pair<int,int> P
typedef set<P>  PS
typedef map<P,PS>  PSM  // say the point at right edgexbottomedge defines the BLOCK you want.
 PSM psm(400)
```

Tada.  That is what you are looking for...